# How to configure ASP.NET Core Identity endpoints in a Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity, endpoint

Recently, version 8 of Identity was released. In this version, Identity endpoints can be used for tasks like user registration, etc. Additionally, Jwt Bearer can be used instead of cookies. However, once I have my initial configuration working:

program.cs

```
builder.Services
    .AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();

...

app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>().AllowAnonymous();
```

I would like to know how I can view the controller that Identity creates with all these endpoints in my Visual Studio environment. Is it possible to change things, for example, the seed with which the JWT is signed?

My initial code works, but I would like to add some things, like the seed phrase, and understand the logic behind the endpoints